# Sum attribute in overlapping polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, union

I have a month's worth of snowfall contoured polygons in one feature class. Polygons represent one day and has a field called SNOWFALL. How can I display the total snowfall for the month? I have the standard license.

I have attached a screenshot of the identity tool on a polygon.

I tried a union, then after that a dissolve by Shape area with Sum of Snowfall checked. However many polygons have the same area so that didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Add X, Y fields (**long integer**) to polygon layer. Compute polygon centroid X and Y
2. Add field pgonID - text. Populate it using [X] & "_" & [Y]
3. Use pgonID as case field in Summary Statistics to total [SNOWFALL]
4. Remove duplicates from original (make a copy 1st) using field pgonID
5. Join it with summary statistics table

Comment: Use long integer even if my x y attributes will be decimal degrees?

Comment: No, make them double. But modify calculator expression [pgonID]=str([X]*10000) & "_" & str([Y]*10000). Instead of removing duplicates (step 4) you might as well use Dissolve on that field.

Answer (score 1):

add X and Y fields to your polygons, the use the field calculator to compute the X and Y coordinates.

With these X any Y coordinates, create a new layer of points

Use spatial join (right click > join and relate > join > join based on location) between the points and the polygons, with the option "each polygon have a summary of the points that fall within it" (obviously you want the sum of snowfall)

Comment: Thanks. Do I add the X and Y fields to my layer after I do a union?

Comment: yes, you need the points to be duplicated every time a polygon is duplicated

Comment: My solution assumes polygons are identical shapes sitting on the top of each other

Comment: OK. I am running radouxju's solution right now. If I do a union first the polygons will be identical shapes on top of each other.