# Setting Merge Rules in Spatial Join for 90+ fields or changing default merge rule?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, spatial-join

I am trying to perform a spatial join that will aggregate about 90 fields using a SUM function.

In the Field Map I get the option to right click on each field and set the merge rule to SUM.

This would be extremely tedious for me to do, especially since I have to perform such a spatial join for 30+ layers.

Is there a way to change the "default" merge rule option to SUM instead of FIRST? How about change the field merge rules in bulk?

Screenshot to illustrate the point

[image: Field Map List]

Comment: Can you provide screen shot of the fields you are look to aggregate?

Comment: @hannbroo added screenshot in post

Comment: I thought there would have been an environment setting for this, but I don't seem to be able to find one.  Could probably be done with a bit of arcpy, although field mappings in arcpy can be tricky too

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at an alternative workflow which involves these untested steps:

1. Spatial Join (or Union if dealing with overlapping polygons)
2. Summary Statistics
3. Join Field

Comment: My problem is that the spatial join step requires manual input of merge rules for each field individually (please refer screenshot above)

Comment: This suggestion would not use merge rules of Spatial Join. That logic would be in the Summary Statistics. At the moment I am putting this forward as an idea without being 100% clear about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to "add" overlapping polygons, each of which has the fields above, to create a layer holding the cumulative total. The problem with Summary Statistics is that it doesn't take spatial location into account, so I would have to perform a spatial join with a temporary grid to assign unique IDs to each polygon, and then perform the summary statistics with the unique ID as "case". That is also rather tedious.

Comment: You made no mention of overlapping features in your question but, in any event, I think Summary Statistics on a Union-ed feature class will give some useful data to work from but ArcPy cursors may provide more flexibility if you need it.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think it was necessary since all I needed was to set Merge Rules in bulk. It was my understanding that Union will discard the fields of join features that overlap if they are identical to the target features, or am I missing something? Summary Statistics would then only be performed on the original data set, which is of no use.

Comment: Union uses planar enforcement but maintains a field for every input feature class which enables it to store the overlap relationships.

Comment: How many polygon layers to add?

Comment: @FelixIP question seems to say 30+ so if no Advanced license will need to do pair wise Unions.

Comment: Is there any overlap within feature classes or only between feature classes?

Comment: Originally the overlap is only between feature classes, however I merged these layers into one (which now has overlapping features) and I am attempting to perform a spatial join on the output with a "mother" layer which would aggregate the fields that you see in the screenshot above. Perhaps there is a way to work directly with the original non-overlapping features?  Please refer to what follows for my original problem which I am still trying to solve: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228363/aggregating-multiple-layers-while-preserving-values-using-arcmap

Comment: I think it is time you used the [edit] button to heavily revise your question with all the other details that are emerging from comments.